# Best way to pre-tag a dataset of words to be used to train a MITIE entity extractor on?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I want to use the MITIE NER trainer to build an entity extractor. However is there a more efficient way to tag the training data rather than hard coding the location of each one?

Thanks in advance :)